# How do I create a MySql database connection that returns results to a text file?

Tags: c#, mysql, file-io

I want to write a MySql statement that will connect to the database, select a column from the table, then output that data to a text file to a specific location on my computer.  I have searched the internet for a couple days now and don't seem to find the answer I am looking for.  I am fairly new to c#, MySql, and Visual Studio.  I am just trying to learn how to write the correct statements and get the desired result.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace NewPractice
{
    public class Connect
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string results = @"server=111.111.11.111; userid=anyone;
                password=anypassword; database=anydatabase";    
            MySqlConnection conn = null;

            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(results);
                conn.Open();
                //Console.WriteLine(
                File.WriteAllLines(
                    @"C:\Documents and Settings\anyone\My Documents\Tests\testoutput.txt", 
                    results.ToArray());
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: (0)", ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing the contents of the `result` string to the file, not the data you're attempting to select. You need to run a sql command and get a `SqlDataReader` object to write your data to the file.

```
string results = @"server=111.111.11.111; userid=anyone; 
    password=anypassword; database=anydatabase";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(results);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
MySqlDataReader reader;
command.CommandText = "select * from mycustomers";
connection.Open();
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
using(var sw = new StreamWriter("C:\MyPath\MyFile.txt"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var row = (IDataRecord)reader;
        sw.WriteLine(row["myColumn"]);
    }
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you, sometimes when we are new at writing code, we need some specific direction.  I have searched for two days.  I sometimes feel other programmers tend to forget they had to start somewhere and needed help too

Answer (score 1):

If the database is on your local machine you can use 'select .. into outfile'. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html. This will write to a folder on the server so it's not v useful if it's a different machine and you can't copy from there.

Comment: the server address (as in the code) is an ip address so the database is not on the local machine.  I want the file to be saved on the local machine as a text file.  I'm sorry I wasn't very clear

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tutorials out there for accessing MySQL from .NET.
This is one: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/

In any language, there are a few simple steps to read from a database:

```
1. connect to the database.
2. execute a query
3. iterate through the results of the query
4. close the connection.
```

What you are doing in your code is connecting to the database and then trying to write the connection information to a file.

Comment: I want the file to be saved on the local machine as a text file. I'm sorry I wasn't very clear .  The tutorial you listed is one I have already looked at.  While it is good to learn how to connect, it does not explain how to have the results of the query saved to my local machine.

Comment: Take a look at this one then. It shows how to connect, query and iterate through a resultset.  Instead of writing to the Console, you can write to your file.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793050/working-with-mysql-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: I didn't see this last response till now, thanks, that does help